# Billable status for time records through API

Tags: activecollab

We have a script were we can mark time records in Active Collab as paid through the API. But it seems that this no longer works. We get "$billable_status is not valid param value” when we try to send billable_status = 3 to PUT /projects/$projectId/time-records/$recordId. This used to work, but since one of the latest updates it seems "broken".

Anyone know of a new way we can mark records as paid through the API?

I've contacted support@activecollab.com, but they redirect me over here.

Comment: It's a bug. We'll probably figure out what's causing the problem, but please send us payload that you are sending, just in case. Thanks and sorry for the interruption.

Comment: @Ilija literately just billable status, to PUT https://app.activecollab.com/$accountId/api/v1/projects/$projectId/time-records/$recordId {"billable_status":3}

Comment: @Ilija can this be resolved quickly as we use this for our monthly invoicing, and that will happen tomorrow.

Comment: Fix has been deployed today.

Comment: This works again, thank you!